# Select items from an array based on specific values

Tags: arrays, sorting, vuejs2

I currently get a list of sporting events back and store them as a Vue data object. Each item in the array has key value pairs for the Home Win, Away Win, Draw. Using `v-for` I want to list all team names of type "home" and type "away" but the order of the these items are not being returned in order.

So using `v-for` I'm trying to understand how I can render:

> `<div>`**teamname value of type home** vs **teamname value of type away**`</div>`

```json
{
    "data": [
        {
            "options": [
                {
                    "type": "home",
                    "teamname": "xxx"
                },
                {
                    "type": "away",
                    "teamname": "yyy"
                },
                {
                    "type": "draw",
                    "teamname": "no winner"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "options": [
                {
                    "type": "away",
                    "teamname": "yyy"
                },
                {
                    "type": "draw",
                    "teamname": "no winner"
                },
                {
                    "type": "home",
                    "teamname": "xxx"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "options": [
                {
                    "type": "draw",
                    "teamname": "no winner"
                },
                {
                    "type": "home",
                    "teamname": "xxx"
                },
                {
                    "type": "away",
                    "teamname": "yyy"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: So to be clear, you're looking to display a `<div>{{ teamname value of type home }} vs {{ teamname value of type away }}</div>` for each `option` object in the incoming data?

Comment: That is exactly right. for each item in the array

Answer (score 1):

A small snippet with one solution:

```js
const results = {
  "data": [{
      "options": [{
          "type": "home",
          "teamname": "xxx"
        },
        {
          "type": "away",
          "teamname": "yyy"
        },
        {
          "type": "draw",
          "teamname": "no winner"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "options": [{
          "type": "away",
          "teamname": "yyy"
        },
        {
          "type": "draw",
          "teamname": "no winner"
        },
        {
          "type": "home",
          "teamname": "xxx"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "options": [{
          "type": "draw",
          "teamname": "no winner"
        },
        {
          "type": "home",
          "teamname": "xxx"
        },
        {
          "type": "away",
          "teamname": "yyy"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Vue.component("DisplayResult", {
  props: ['result'],
  computed: {
    home() {
      return this.result.find(({
        type
      }) => type === "home")["teamname"]
    },
    away() {
      return this.result.find(({
        type
      }) => type === "away")["teamname"]
    },
  },
  template: `
    <div>{{ home }} vs. {{ away }}</div>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      results: [],
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.results = results.data
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <display-result
        v-for="({ options }, i) in results"
        :key="i"
        :result="options"
      />
    </div>
  `
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

With this solution you have granular control on the display of the results: styling, content, etc is in one component, while the source of data is in the parent. The templates are "clear", free of any code, so maintaining & updating is easier.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```html
...
  <div v-for="(item, index) in data" key="index">
    {{ item.options.find(op => op.type === "home").teamname }} vs {{ item.options.find(op => op.type === "away").teamname }}
  </div>
...
```

You'll loop through each item in your incoming `data` object, and for each one, use an `Array.prototype.find()` to retrieve the desired team.

Runnable example is below:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      data: [{
          "options": [{
              "type": "home",
              "teamname": "xxx"
            },
            {
              "type": "away",
              "teamname": "yyy"
            },
            {
              "type": "draw",
              "teamname": "no winner"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "options": [{
              "type": "away",
              "teamname": "yyy"
            },
            {
              "type": "draw",
              "teamname": "no winner"
            },
            {
              "type": "home",
              "teamname": "xxx"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "options": [{
              "type": "draw",
              "teamname": "no winner"
            },
            {
              "type": "home",
              "teamname": "xxx"
            },
            {
              "type": "away",
              "teamname": "yyy"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h3>Home vs. Away</h3>
  <div v-for="(item, index) in data" key="index">
    {{ item.options.find(op => op.type === "home").teamname }} vs {{ item.options.find(op => op.type === "away").teamname }}
  </div>
</div>
```

---

One final note;
If you have control over the input, and you know the structure will be consistent, it might make sense to send the `options` array over as a single object. Instead of having 3 objects each with `type` and `teamname` keys, you'd instead use a single object with `home`/`away`/`draw` all as separate keys, like this:

```js
options: {
  home: 'home-team-name',
  away: 'away-team-name',
  draw: 'no winner',
}
```

This way, instead of using `item.options.find(op => op.type === "home").teamname`, you could just access the field directly:

```js
{{ item.options.home }} vs {{ item.options.away }}
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      data: [{
          "options": {
            "home": "xxx",
            "away": "yyy",
            "draw": "no winner",
          }
        },
        {
          "options": {
            "away": "yyy",
            "draw": "no winner",
            "home": "xxx",
          }
        },
        {
          "options": {
            "draw": "no winner",
            "home": "xxx",
            "away": "yyy",
          }
        }
      ],
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h3>Home vs. Away</h3>
  <div v-for="(item, index) in data" key="index">
    {{ item.options.home }} vs {{ item.options.away }}
  </div>
</div>
```